# Why do Rust's operators have the type Output variable?

Tags: generics, operator-overloading, rust

I've been reading through the Rust book online and I've reached [4.1, Operators and Overloading](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/operators-and-overloading.html). I noticed that [`std::ops::Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) defines it as `fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;` with a `type Output` defined separately in the trait.

I understand what's going on here: the `add` function accepts the left hand side as `self`, and the right hand side as the generic parameter type `RHS`.

I want to know why is the output type defined with the `Output` alias, instead of being another generic (ex. `Add<RHS, Output>`)? Is it just a convention, or is there a specific reason to it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While functions operate on variables, you can think of traits as functions that operate on types. When thought of this way, the type parameters serve as inputs to the function and associated types serve as outputs.

Since `Output` is an associated type, for two types `A` and `B` that we wish to `impl Add`, we are restricted to picking a single `Output` type. Were `Output` a type parameter, we could `impl Add` for `A` and `B` in a myriad of ways.

For example, let us define a `Mul` trait where `Output` is a parameter:

```rust
trait Mul<RHS, Output> {
    fn mul(self, rhs: RHS) -> Output;
}
```

Now let us define a `Complex` type:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Complex {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

impl Complex {
    fn new(x: f64, y: f64) -> Complex {
        Complex { x: x, y: y }
    }
}
```

We want to be able to multiply it by `f64`:

```rust
impl Mul<f64, Complex> for Complex {
    fn mul(self, rhs: f64) -> Complex {
        Complex::new(self.x * rhs, self.y * rhs)
    }
}
```

This all works fine. However, we could come up with a second implementation:

```rust
impl Mul<f64, f64> for Complex {
    fn mul(self, rhs: f64) -> f64 {
        self.x * rhs
    }
}
```

When we multiply a `Complex` by a `f64` now, it is ambiguous which implementation should be called, and extra type information is needed to be supplied by the caller. By making `Output` an associated type, this is disallowed. The following code throws a compiler error for conflicting implementations:

```rust
impl std::ops::Mul<f64> for Complex {
    type Output = Complex;
    fn mul(self, rhs: f64) -> Complex {
        Complex::new(self.x * rhs, self.y * rhs)
    }
}

impl std::ops::Mul<f64> for Complex {
    type Output = f64;
    fn mul(self, rhs: f64) -> Complex {
        self.x * rhs
    }
}
```

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=46da7bcb0317b0c3f3843627844b7bbc&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I see. So, with `Mul<RHS, Output>`, you need to set your variable type as `x: Complex` or `x: f64` in order to decide which one you need, so the `type Output` decision was primarily a 'tidiness' decision. This looks like the best answer but I want to be sure I understand it; do I follow?

Comment: That is how I understand it, yeah.

Comment: And similarly, any attempts to 'overwrite' the standard implementation will be met with failure, meaning that once a type has a defined `std::ops::Mul<T>` for any given `T`, it can be relied on to be the *only* implementation. Okay, I think I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's about who gets to specify the output type.  Generally when you multiply two types, say `f64` by `f64`, it's clear what the type of the result should be: `f64`.  It wouldn't make sense for the caller to ask for a result type of `String` - so it doesn't really make sense as an input.

I can imagine some cases where you might want the choice different output, but they're a bit niche (say `u32` * `u32` returning the full `u64` result?); plus if there were more than one option, how do you specify which one you want?  While you could write `Add<u32, u64>::add(a, b)`, it would make simple expressions like `a*b*c` ambiguous and make type inference much harder!

Comment: This isn't the question. In my question I asked, 'why is the output type defined with the `Output` alias, instead of being another generic?' I understand that you might want to specify the output type - I'm not new to programming - but I want to know why they take _this particular approach_ to it instead of the seemingly more obvious `Add<RHS, Output>` approach?

Comment: `Add<RHS, Output>` would made `Output` an input type parameter, but it's not an input: it's a function of the LHS (Self) and RHS. I'll try to rework my answer to be clearer.